# How to find a element dependant on data-path and change a class within

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use JS to find the below section and change the class from `fa-list-ol` to `fa-car` but I cant seem to get it to change. Any help appreciated!

PS: I want to go: If `data-path=test` then find the `i` class containing `fa-list-ol` and changing it to required field.

I can use Jquery or JS. Just once it can work I am happy

```
<li class="pl-folder" data-path="test">
    <i class="fa fa-bars pl-action" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-pl-menu-playlist" title="Actions"></i>
    <span>
        <i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i>
        hello world
    </span>
</li>
```

JS (Now i no i have [3] <-- i dont want this i just want it to auto find it as i have over 100 lists!):

```
var attrValue = document.getElementsByName('pl-folder')[3].getAttribute("data-path");
if (attrValue == "test") {
    document.getElementsByName('pl-folder')[3].className = "fa fa-car";
}
```

Comment: use document.getElementsByClassName instead of document.getElementsByName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("li[data-path='test']").each( function(){
    $(this).find('i.fa-list-ol').toggleClass('fa-list-ol requiredClass');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="pl-folder" data-path="test">
    <i class="fa fa-bars pl-action" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-pl-menu-playlist" title="Actions"></i>
    <span>
        <i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i>
        hello world
    </span>
  </li>
```

```js
$("li[data-path='test']").each( function(){
    $(this).find('i.fa-list-ol').removeClass('fa-list-ol').addClass('requiredClass');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="pl-folder" data-path="test">
    <i class="fa fa-bars pl-action" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-pl-menu-playlist" title="Actions"></i>
    <span>
        <i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i>
        hello world
    </span>
  </li>
```

Comment: As much as the first one worked, it replaced the first `i` which i didnt want, this finds the exact class and replaces perfectly! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to achieve what you require is to use jQuery's `filter()` to find the `li` with the matching `data-path` attribute value, then traverse the DOM to find its child `i` element and toggle the required classes. Try this:

```js
$('.pl-folder').filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('path') == 'test';
}).find('span i').toggleClass('fa-list-ol fa-car');
```

```css
.fa-car {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="pl-folder" data-path="test">
    <i class="fa fa-bars pl-action" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-pl-menu-playlist" title="Actions"></i>
    <span>
        <i class="fa fa-list-ol">TEST</i>
        hello world
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="pl-folder" data-path="foo">
    <i class="fa fa-bars pl-action" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-pl-menu-playlist" title="Actions"></i>
    <span>
        <i class="fa fa-list-ol">FOO</i>
        hello world
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="pl-folder" data-path="bar">
    <i class="fa fa-bars pl-action" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-pl-menu-playlist" title="Actions"></i>
    <span>
        <i class="fa fa-list-ol">BAR</i>
        hello world
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note that I only added some text within the `<i>` elements to make the effect of the class change visible.

You could also simplify the jQuery to use an attribute selector, but note this will only work if the `data` attirbute is set in the DOM, not in jQuery's internal cache:

```
$('.pl-folder[data-path="test"]').find('span i').toggleClass('fa-list-ol fa-car');
```

Comment: Amazing!! Wow, thank you so much! Really appreciate it:)

Comment: I just noticed, with the code set it is now adding `fa-list-ol fa-car` to the first `i` class? So its coming up with: `class="fa fa-bars pl-action fa-list-ol fa-car"` I need that one to stay with just: `fa fa-bars pl-action`. How do i achieve this? thanks.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that you had 2 `i` elements. You just need to use `find('span i')` instead. I updated my answer for you